# Unable to read the tsv data using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I have verified the encode of .tsv file. But while reading the .tsv file using pandas dataframe, I am getting the error like the below error.

Below is endcode i have found for my .tsv file :

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\xxxx\\xxxxx\\sample.tsv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

But as a result, using pandas to read the dataframe i am getting the below error :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 16: character maps to <undefined>
```

Here is the code snippet i used :

```
read_tsv = 
       pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\xxxx\\xxxx\\sample.tsv',sep='\t', encoding='cp1252')
                   
print(read_tsv.head())
```

Could you please help me for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\xxxxx\\sample.tsv', skiprows=2, encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Anyway you should try all options using different separators (like ";" or "," or "\n")
But if you can open this file in another program and take a screenshot then show me how it looks

Comment: @vovakiradan, Surely...I will let you know

Comment: excel can open csv, maybe you'll try it?

Comment: i am getting the error like :  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte